# background color not changing when editing bootstrap.css file of MVC template project VS 2013

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to change the background color of navigation bar of MVC project. I tried changing the "bootstrap.css" file under Content folder.

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #222222;
  border-color: #080808;
}
```

I changed the color to #5A2506, but after re-loading it is still showing #222222 color. But when I change the color via developer tools of chrome the color is changed ,why?

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #5A2506;
  border-color: #080808;
}
```

Comment: May be it's loading from cache in browser press ctrl+f5 to refresh page

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: yes I was doing Ctrl+F5.

Comment: Then css is defined somewhere else as well

Comment: Can you put a `!important` keyword to the background-color to see if that fixes it?

`background-color: #5A2506 !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I found that, when using Chrome I've to clear *cache* every time I make changes in CSS. But with firefox there is no such issues. Does any one else face the same issue?